# $A = BC$ matrix equality, can I consider $C$ as an output and analyse its behaviour?

Tags: linear-algebra

Hi Math masters at SO,

I post to ask for a little help with math about my current project work. To make it simple, I have a $2$ dimensional vector of inputs, $A$, and a $6$ dimensional vector of outputs $C$. $B$ is a $2\times 6$ matrix of parameters.

Normally, the analysis is made in the reversed direction, that is, $A$ is the vector of outputs and $C$ that of inputs.

How may I carry out this analysis? For example, if $B_{ij}$ or $A_{mn}$ is tuned in magnitude, how will that affect the elements of $C$?

I don't even know how to name this math to google it :D. So, I also need some reference for further reading.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$B$ is "fat" (that is, it has more columns than rows). Assuming that $B$ is [full rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_%28linear_algebra%29), this implies that for any fixed $A$, there are many (infinitely many, a four dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^6$) vectors $C$ such that

$$A=BC.$$

So, on the face of it, I think you are going to have a hard time treating $C$ *as an output caused by some input* $A$.

For more info I'd recommend checking out lectures $1-9$ of [here](http://see.stanford.edu/see/lecturelist.aspx?coll=17005383-19c6-49ed-9497-2ba8bfcfe5f6) and the videos in [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra).

Comment: what I'm doing now to solve C is by using pseudo-inverse, i.e., $C=B^\dagger*A$ and it seems I achieve only 1 C as output. This means I'm lack of the others? how may I solve this properly?

Comment: So $B^\dagger A$ is the *minimum norm solution*, that is, it is the vector $C$ with smallest $||C||_2$ such that $A=BC$. The other vectors that satisfy $A=BC$ are of the form $C=B^\dagger A +v$, where $v$ lies in the kernel of $B$. With regards to "how may I solve this properly" - depends, what would you like to do?

Comment: I mean the specific solution $C$ with smallest $\|C\|_2$ is a specific one and my original question to observe $C$ (as output) with others being tuned is feasible? Given that calculation of C is known well